# TypeScript literal number type not being calculated

Tags: typescript

I'm confused with such behavior: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAclC8UCMUA+UC0L0AYBQeA9IVAPIDSeAZgK4B2AxsAJYD2dUwEAzsAPpIAFAEMATgHMAXLACU0uAG88UKKIjAaojmPF4AvgWJlKtRi3ace-AEwiJ8ubChKVajVqg606JPsMkAfgCoABVwaAByOhoAWwAjCFEIqGZuKDpWYE9ubmZxOmE4gBtoYFZOcKgImAiAOmp6JjYOLl4+AGY7KVl5Z2VVdU0OAFlhYAALWsLuLpk-IhIKBrNmyzaAFi6HXpcB9xGxyenZ7Nh5oyXTJotW-gBWLZ6oXlFmOnE+lSMAAWBuDAgAA9IEwAaJRKxRP03EMoKMJlM4jMdDJTi83roDAsoEFjMtri0rHwAGyPGCORTQwYeQQYLwAKig61RwjSMH0QA).

```js
type N = 1 | -1 | 0

// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'N'.
function test_3(arg: N): N {
  return Math.abs(arg)
}

// OK!?
function test_5(arg: N): N {
  return (-arg * 4) as N
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is not smart enough to understand that `Math.abs()` would return `1` when given `-1` or `0` when given `0`. All it knows is that return type of `Math.abs()` is `number` and `number` does not extend the return type `N` of the function `test_3`.

So if you tell TypeScript that you are certain that `Math.abs()` returns a member of `N` (with `as N`) TypeScript will not show an error.

Answer (score 1):

Math.args returns a number. The function is not able to understand that as your entry is of type `N`, then your output will also be of type `N`. For it, it will always be a number as output.

That's why you have the first error indicating that a number can not be considered as a type `N`.

For the second case, you explicitly tell Typescript with the `as` that your number is actually of type `N`, so even if that's wrong, typescript is ok with that because it can easily consider a number as a `N` type.